# Proof of the existence of an invariant subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space with $\dim(V)<\infty$ and $f∈End(V)$. If $f$ has an eigenvector,
 there is a $f$-invariant subspace $U$ of $V$ with $\dim(U) = \dim(V)-1$.

Would be really happy for any kind of help, thanks in advance.

Comment: @hardmath This is not a special case of that question because that question is only about diagonalizable operators.

Comment: @T.Gunn:  Yes, you are correct.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the minimal polynomial of $f$ factors as $(t - \lambda)^\nu \psi(t)$ where $(t - \lambda) \nmid \psi(t)$. Then $$V = \ker(f - \lambda)^\nu \oplus \ker \psi(f)$$ and notice that both of these subspaces are $f$-invariant. It therefore suffices to find a codimension 1 subspace $U_0$ of $\ker(f - \lambda)^\nu$ which is $f$-invariant because then we can take $U = U_0 \oplus \ker \psi(f)$. Hence, we may assume that the minimal polynomial of $f$ is just $(t - \lambda)^\nu$.

What does the structure of such an operator look like? Well, applying the Jordan normal form (which can be applied here since we now know that the minimal polynomial splits in our field), we know that $V$ admits a basis in which $f$ is a direct sum of Jordan blocks:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & & &  &  \\
1 & \lambda & & &  \\
& 1 & \lambda & & \\
& & \ddots & \ddots & \\
& & & 1 & \lambda
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Let $V = W_1 \oplus W_2 \oplus \cdots W_r$ where $f$ restricted to any $W_i$ has a basis that corresponding to a Jordan block. Note that $W_i$ is $f$-invariant. By the argument we used at the end of the first paragraph, we may assume that $V = W_1$.

We know that $V$ has a Jordan-basis $v, (f - \lambda) v, (f - \lambda)^2 v, \dots, (f - \lambda)^{k} v$. With this basis, and keeping the above matrix form in mind, $(f - \lambda) v, (f - \lambda)^2 v, \dots, (f - \lambda)^{k} v$ span a codimension-1, $f$-invariant subspace of $V$, as required.

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space.

If **null space** of $V$ is not zero then dimension of **range** of $f$ is $\leq n-1$, say $C=\{w_1,w_2,\dots,w_{k}\}$ be the basis of the **range** of $f$, now we can extend this basis to a basis of $V$, so assume that the basis of $V$ is $B=\{w_1,w_2,...w_{k},v_1,v_2\dots v_{n-k}\}$.

Now there exists a $m$, such that $v_m\not\in span(C)$

Now take $S=<w_1,w_2,...w_{k},v_1,v_2\dots v_{m-1},v_{m+1},...v_{n-k}>$
This is clearly a $T$-invariant subspace of dimension $n-1$ as $f(S)\in Span(C)\in S$.

(Note that <> denotes the span of the elements)

Now assume **null space** is $0$ then if $f$ has an eigenvector $v_1$ then it has a non-zero eigenvalue $\lambda$ corresponding to $v_1$.

So $f(v_1)=\lambda v_1$.

Define $f'(v)=f(v)-\lambda v$.

Clearly $f'$ is a linear operator and it's **null** space is not zero, hence it has a $n-1$ dimensional subspace $S'$ such that $f'(S')\in S'$ as proved earlier.

Now for each vector $s\in S'$,

$f(s)=f'(s)+ \lambda s$, so $f(s)\in S'$

So $f(S')\in S'$, and $S'$ is of dimension $n-1$, hence we solved our problem!!

Comment: He wants the codim 1 not the dimension of the invariant subspace.

Comment: Why will the space be f-invariant ?

Comment: This argument doesn't work because there is no reason for $K$ to be $f$-invariant. For the matrix $$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, $$ your argument would diagonalize the matrix, which we know cannot be done.

Comment: "Clearly f(S)=S∈S" cannot be justified. For example, take the matrix in my previous comment, it has $(0,1)^T$ as an eigenvector. I complete this to a basis $\{(1,0)^T, (0,1)^T\}$ for $V$. Now apply $f^{-1}$ to get $\{(1, -1)^T, (0,1)^T\}$. Toss out the eigenvector to get $S = \langle (1, -1)^T \rangle$. But we can plainly see that $f(S) \ne S$.

Comment: Please check the revised solution

Comment: It's good now, just some formatting issues. You want to use `\langle . . . \rangle` instead of `< . . . >`, `span` should be written as `\operatorname{span}`, and on the last line you should write `f(S') \subseteq S'`. Also at the beginning, all the vectors $v_1, \dots, v_{n - k}$ are not in $\operatorname{span}(C) = \operatorname{ran}(f)$ by definition. You also used $T$ for the first half and $f$ for the second half.